# Error while using Python wifi module

Tags: python, python-2.7, wifi

> When i try to run the scan operation using the wifi library as mentioned in the documentation, i get the following error.

```
 (lsbaws)Keshav:bin root# wifi scan

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Keshav/Documents/Github/Webserver/webserver/lsbaws/bin/wifi", line 202, in <module>
  args.func(args)
  File "/Users/Keshav/Documents/Github/Webserver/webserver/lsbaws/bin/wifi", line 51, in scan_command
  print_table([[cell.signal, cell.ssid, 'protected' if cell.encrypted else 'unprotected'] for cell in Cell.all(args.interface)])
  File "/Users/Keshav/Documents/Github/Webserver/webserver/lsbaws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wifi/scan.py", line 29, in all
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
  process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception

  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that this python wifi library does not work on mac.

An alternative to do wifi scanning is using the tool that comes in mac called airports.

To start using the tool -

```
$ cd /usr/sbin
$ sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport
```

The airports -I flag is useful

Also just typing airports will open up the partly explicit manual page

Refrence link - [Airports Example](http://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/)